# Как кикнуть всех игроков

Tags: lua, roblox

```
workspace.WindowEvent.Changed:Connect(function(hit)
  local plr = game.Players:GetPlayerFromCharacter(hit.Parent)
  if workspace.WindowEvent.Value == true then
    wait(5)
    if workspace.WindowEvent.Value == true then
      plr:Kick("asdf")
    end
  end
end)
```

Нужно чтобы игрока кикало через **serverside** скрипт,
`WindowEven.Value` это bool(true/false)

Comment: найти функцию  в `game.Players` которая перечисляет игроков или найти какой-то массив с игроками... пройти по ним в цикле и кикнуть.

Answer (score 0):

Лучше сделай вызов функции, либо адаптируй этот скрипт:

```
for _,v in pairs(game.Players:GetPlayers()) do
if v:IsA("Player") then
v:Kick("rise you motherfucker")
end end
```

Тут `for v in pairs` используется.